# Plotting data using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot my data with legends for the black line as well but I don't know how it can be done so that "MYLINE" will appear on the right side under MY2? and how to control the colour and properties of this line e.g colour, thickness,...?

```
MY1_DIS_REF$METHOD <- "MY1"
MY1_plot<-MY1_DIS_REF[,-c(5,6,7)]
MY2_DIS_REF$METHOD <- "MY2"
MY2_plot<-MY2_DIS_REF[,-c(5,6,7)]
MY1andMY2_PLOT <- rbind(MY1_plot,MY2_plot)

ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=MY1andMY2_PLOT,aes(X,Y,color=METHOD),alpha=0.5)+
  geom_path(data=line,aes(V1,V2,group=B1,),size=1)+
  xlab("X")+
  ylab("Y")+
  facet_wrap(~B1,scales = "free")+
  theme_bw()+coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding aes(color = "MYLINE"") into the `geom_path()` call. You can edit other attributes like that too, e.g. `size = 3`

Comment: @G_T Thank you but now the line is drawn on the points in the legend as shown here:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/bu9wc95ns8h7dpw/Screen%20Shot%202020-11-16%20at%208.08.52%20PM.png?dl=0 Also how to set the colours of each? Is it random that now it became red green and blue?

Comment: can you share a piece of your data so we can help you easier? i cannot reproduce your plot.. please, copy and paste the output of `dput(MY1_DIS_REF)` and `dput(MY2_DIS_REF)` into you question.

Comment: @rodolfoksveiga You can find the MY1andMY2_PLOT and line in this link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cybaqgbctgo55co/AADwTkKXZdSpY-tZafDgJ7U7a?dl=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a separate legend for the line by using a different aesthetic to the one the current legend is using:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=MY1andMY2_PLOT,aes(X,Y,color=METHOD),alpha=0.5)+
  geom_path(data=line,aes(V1,V2, group=B1, linetype = "Myline"), size=1)+
  xlab("X")+
  ylab("Y")+
  facet_wrap(~B1,scales = "free")+
  theme_bw()+coord_flip()
```

[image]

You can change the other aesthetics with arguments outside of aesthetics, e.g. thickness is controlled by `size`:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=MY1andMY2_PLOT,aes(X,Y,color=METHOD),alpha=0.5)+
  geom_path(data=line,aes(V1,V2, group=B1, linetype = "Myline"), size=3)+
  xlab("X")+
  ylab("Y")+
  facet_wrap(~B1,scales = "free")+
  theme_bw()+coord_flip()
```

[image]

You can change colors by editing the color scale (red and blue are default):

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=MY1andMY2_PLOT,aes(X,Y,color=METHOD),alpha=0.5)+
  geom_path(data=line,aes(V1,V2, group=B1, linetype = "Myline"), size=1)+
  xlab("X")+
  ylab("Y")+
  facet_wrap(~B1,scales = "free")+
  theme_bw()+coord_flip() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("orange", "pink"))
```

[image]

Edit: Change line colour:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=MY1andMY2_PLOT,aes(X,Y,color=METHOD),alpha=0.5)+
  geom_path(data=line,aes(V1,V2, group=B1, linetype = "Myline"), size=3, colour = "blue") +
  xlab("X")+
  ylab("Y")+
  facet_wrap(~B1,scales = "free")+
  theme_bw()+coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to change the colour of the line? and change the legend name from "linetype" to something else?

Comment: i guess setting `geom_path(data=line,aes(V1,V2, group=B1, DESIRED_NAME = "Myline", colour = "DESIRED_COLOUR")` will do the trick

Comment: @rodolfoksveiga When I do this "Myline" legend never appears. Any advice?

Comment: `"Myline" is whatever you want to call your line in the legend. check the legend in the plot and you'll see the name of the black line is "Myline"

Comment: @rodolfoksveiga I understand but when I did this `geom_path(data=line,aes(V1,V2, group=B1, DESIRED_NAME = "Myline", colour = "DESIRED_COLOUR")` nothing appeared in the legend

Comment: Make sure `colour = "DESIRED_COLOUR"` is outside the `aes()` in `geom_path()`

Comment: i have sent you an answer for this question.. i hope it helps..!

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to rename the legend, you can do the following:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=MY1andMY2_PLOT,aes(X,Y,color=METHOD),alpha=0.5)+
  geom_path(data=line,aes(V1,V2, group = B1, linetype = "MyLine"), size=3, colour = "blue") +
  labs(x = "X", y = "Y", linetype = "DESIRED_LINETYPE_NAME", color = "DESIRED_COLOR_NAME")+
  facet_wrap(~B1,scales = "free")+
  theme_bw()+coord_flip()
```